# "Open Camera" app removed resolution of 176x144 in newer devices, how do I restore it?

Tags: applications, camera, samsung-galaxy-s-20

The [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) open-source app uses the Camera2 API for listing the available photo resolutions. On older devices such as Samsung Galaxy S8 and S9, users had low resolutions such as 176x144, but on S20 and S22, that resolution isn't available.

[image]

How do I restore it?

Comment: It might help to know why you need it, in case there are other solutions.

Comment: i need low resolutions to incorporate photos of medical conditions with small resolutions in my medical conditions atlas , since its an atlas of diseases with thousands of photos and including photos of higher resolution would result in a file which is extremely large